# Index mysql corrupted?

Tags: mysql, indexing, corrupt

There is a mysql table and I think that unique index corrupted.
When i execute the follow sql:

```
SELECT field_b FROM table LIMIT 0,10
```

the response is NULL (10 rows with NULL).

BUT if I execute

```
SELECT field_b FROM table WHERE field_a = 1
```

I am getting the (non-null) data. What's happening?

The following are the table properties

```
field_a and field_b = INT(11)
field_a = PRIMARY
field_b = UNIQUE INDEX
Table type = INNODB
```

There are 200k+ rows in this table.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the response is NULL'? Do you get zero rows in your result set, or that's what is returned by some SQL wrapper method?

Comment: Mean that's returned 10 rows and all with NULL

Comment: But can't it just mean that first 10 rows of your table just have `field_b` set to `NULL` (it's possible even with UNIQUE constraint in InnoDB)? Try this query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field_b IS NULL` to check this.

Comment: "first 10" -- means the first 10 that it chose to fetch; probably from `INDEX(field_b)`; that is where any NULL values will be.

Answer (score 0):

Try `filed_b` instead of `field_b`

```
SELECT filed_b From table limit 0,10 //spelling mistake
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have duplicate NULL values in a column with a unique index. A unique index only guarantees that non-null values are unique.

As noted by the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html), there is an exception with the BDB storage engine.

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply
>   to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine.

You have at least ten rows where field_b is NULL and they're showing when you issue your query.

To see all of the rows where field_b is NULL try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_b IS NULL
```